# Extract substring using XSLT / XPath using XSLT Transformation (to use in WSO2)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, wso2

I'm quite a newbie in XSLT / XPath ....

I've the following XML message ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soapenv:Body>
   <request xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <gam:process xmlns:gam="http://gamopera.ifpl.csi.it">
     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
     <gam:id>1</gam:id>
     <gam:id>3</gam:id>
     <gam:id>5</gam:id>
     <gam:id>7</gam:id>
     <gam:id>438</gam:id>
     <gam:id>2</gam:id>
     <gam:id>4</gam:id>
     <gam:id>6</gam:id>
     <gam:id>8</gam:id>
    </gam:process>
    <ax2586:good xmlns:ax2586="http://gamopera.ifpl.csi.it">
     <ax2586:id>1</ax2586:id>
     <ax2586:id>3</ax2586:id>
     <ax2586:id>5</ax2586:id>
     <ax2586:id>7</ax2586:id>
    </ax2586:good>
   </request>
  </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

and I'd like to obtain something like this one

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ns:processResponse xmlns:ns="http://gamopera.ifpl.csi.it">
   <ns:return xsi:type="ax2586:Result" xmlns:ax2586="http://dto.gamopera.ifpl.csi.it/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ax2586:good xsi:type="ax2586:ElencoId" xmlns:ax2586="http://gamopera.ifpl.csi.it">
           <ax2586:good>
              <ax2586:id>1</ax2586:id>
              <ax2586:id>3</ax2586:id>
              <ax2586:id>5</ax2586:id>
              <ax2586:id>7</ax2586:id>
           </ax2586:good>
        </ax2586:good>
        <ax2586:message>Message Store does not exist.</ax2586:message>
        <ax2586:statusCode>0</ax2586:statusCode>
        <ax2586:wrong xsi:type="ax2586:ElencoId">
           <ax2586:wrong xmlns:ax2586="http://gamopera.ifpl.csi.it">
              <gam:id xmlns:gam="http://gamopera.ifpl.csi.it" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">438</gam:id>
              <gam:id xmlns:gam="http://gamopera.ifpl.csi.it" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">2</gam:id>
              <gam:id xmlns:gam="http://gamopera.ifpl.csi.it" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">4</gam:id>
              <gam:id xmlns:gam="http://gamopera.ifpl.csi.it" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">6</gam:id>
              <gam:id xmlns:gam="http://gamopera.ifpl.csi.it" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">8</gam:id>
           </ax2586:wrong>
        </ax2586:wrong>
     </ns:return>
  </ns:processResponse>
```

Searching on the web now I've built this XSLT Transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="ns1" select="//*[local-name()='process']/*"/>
   <xsl:variable name="ns2" select="//*[local-name()='good']/*"/>
   <xsl:variable name="difference" select="$ns1[not(.=$ns2)],$ns2[not(.=$ns1)]"/>
   <ax2586:wrong xmlns:ax2586="http://gamopera.ifpl.csi.it">
     <ax2586:wrong><xsl:copy-of select="$difference"/></ax2586:wrong>
   </ax2586:wrong>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

that seems working fine but trying to use it in different XSLT Tester on the web I've found that somewhere it works and somewhere doesn't work so I'm not so sure that this could be the right and portable solution.

NOTE: I've to use it in a WSO2 proxy

Any suggestion or alternative way for obtain the same result?

Thank you very much in advance

Cesare

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting when running it in other XSLT engines? What were those engines?

Comment: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output --> works, http://www.xsltcake.com/ --> doesn't work, no error shown, http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog --> doesn't work, no error shown, http://xslttest.appspot.com/ --> it works ..... You can try copying my XML message and the XSLT transformation ... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsltcake.com` allows you to run XSLT with different engines. In case you would've chosen a .NET XSLT engine, you'd got the following error

> Expected end of the expression, found ','. System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException

The only place where this could belong to is the following XPath

```
$ns1[not(.=$ns2)],$ns2[not(.=$ns1)]
```

and that's certainly not allowed in XSLT 1.0. It seems that you mean

```
$ns1[not(.=$ns2)]
```

And in that case it really works. Live version: http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/3ams3F

Comment: Do you mean that the XPath $ns1[not(.=$ns2)],$ns2[not(.=$ns1)] is something about XSLT 2.0? In any caso I've seen that you live version it's working in xsltcake.com .... Thanks!

Comment: @Cesare [XPath 2.0 to be exact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355191/comma-operator-in-xpath-is-it-like-c). (Also, consider accepting an answer if it helped.)

Comment: I've tried with  the same XPath $ns1[not(.=$ns2)] in all the engines above and now it seems working everywhere